# How can I install Streamster?

Tags: windows, crossover-office

Streamster is a software belong to Marketiva.com (Forex).

I read an article [here](http://my.opera.com/mazwarbz/blog/marketiva-streamser-in-ubuntu-jaunty-jackalope-crossover-7-10) said that he can install Streamster on Ubuntu 11.10. The problem is that I didn't find Crossover version 7.10, can someone give me a .dep file of this app, or give me another solution to install Streamster?

Answer (score 2):

You best bet would to use Play-ON-linux and Wine, then install the proprietary software needed.

For Play on Linux:

Ubuntu
Deb files:

[PlayOnLinux_4.0.16.deb](http://www.playonlinux.com/script_files/PlayOnLinux/4.0.16/PlayOnLinux_4.0.16.deb)

For the Oneiric version

Type the following commands:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_oneiric.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

For the Natty version

Type the following commands:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_natty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Configuring Wine can occasionally be a challenge, but Wine installs quite easily and runs just fine on Ubuntu. To install Wine, use this command at the Terminal prompt:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```